# what is pattern for preg_match_all to get domain name?

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I want get domain name from text, I can do easily for email but can't get for domain name. I used this code to get email address :

```
if (!empty($text)) {
  $res = preg_match_all(
    "/[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\\.[a-z]{2,}/i",
    $text,
    $matches
  );
}
```

What is the pattern for get only domain name from text?

Comment: Have you tried just leaving out the pattern until the `@` for example? Otherwise have a look at the [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20regex%20for%20domain%20names).

Answer (score 1):

```
//if you mean to get domain from any url then this works:
preg_match( '@^(?:http://)?([^/]+)@i', $text, $matches );
$host = $matches[1];

//if you mean to get domain from email address , then this should work
if(preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/" , $email))
{
list($username,$domain)=split('@',$email);
echo "Domain is:'.$domain;
```

Hope this is helpful

Comment: OP wants to find "stackoverflow.com" type domains in text, not email addresses. Searching for an email address is **FAR** easier than searching for a domain name.

Answer (score 0):

When doing email address validation, the most robust RegEx can be found here:
http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php